# How to simulate two 12W lightbulb in series to 220VAC?

Tags: ac, proteus, lamp

How can I simulate two lightbulb of 12Watts in SPICE?

In proteus simulation, **there is only a lamp of adjustable nominal voltage and resistance.** The default is 12V nominal and 24ohms resistance. If I want to simulate two light bulbs(12W) in series to 220VAC, am I correct to not change the nominal of 12V and adjust the resistance to:

$$R= \frac{(220V/\sqrt2)^2}{12W}=2k\Omega$$
**And since there are two bulbs, the total resistance is 4kohms ?**

**OR**

Since, two light bulbs of 12 Watts each will draw 24 Watts in total, the resistance is:

$$R=\frac{(220V/\sqrt2)^2}{24W}=1k\Omega$$

Which of the two resistance will be correct in simulating two 12Watts lightbulb in series?

Comment: What voltage are the lightbulbs designed for?  If they are designed for 12 volts, just moodel them as an open circuit, as they will rapidly blow if connected to 220 volts.

Comment: 1) Lamps using Tungsten are PTC and thus rated hot. Using Ohm’s Law. 2) since Rcold starts around 10% R.hot  , two lamps in series never match perfectly and thus runaway to draw more power on the lower power tolerance , bulb with higher resistance and more voltage drop.  So you never do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since, two light bulbs of 12 Watts each will draw 24 Watts in total ... Which of the two resistance will be correct in simulating two 12Watts lightbulb in series?

Two 12 W lightbulbs will only draw 24 W in total if you connect them in parallel.

If you connect them in series, they will draw less power than a single bulb.

Comment: So it will be 4kohms resistance? And is it okay to leave the nominal voltage to 12V?

Comment: @IwataniNaofumi, I would just use a resistor to model the lamp in SPICE. If you want, just put two resistors in series, each representing a single lamp, and let SPICE work out what the total effect is. (Or do some tests on your own with different ways of modeling the circuit and see which ones give equivalent results)